# Mongoose (or similar ODM) in-memory record registry?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, socket.io, real-time

#### The specification

I have a MongoDB that holds a collection of records, let's call them `operations` for simplicity's sake. Some of these `operations` are running, and the ones that are running each contain a series of `events` that arrive in real time.

I am emitting these events in real-time via `socket.io`, as well as providing an API endpoint that aims to provide an up-to-date list of events.

#### The current situation

Seeing as events arrive in rapid succession (up to thousands per second), it seems suboptimal to `.save()` the record (in this instance I am using Mongoose as the object mapper) upon every incoming event. The current situation is I am throttling the `.save()` call to only get executed every 2 seconds. Because of this, the on-demand list is always anywhere between 0 and 2 seconds behind on the real-time stream whenever the `operation` is ongoing.

#### The proposed optimisation

I am considering implementing an in-memory "registry" of sorts that holds references to all running `operations` (hitting the memory limit is hardly a concern seeing as there will be no more than 10 concurrently running operations in the foreseeable future).

Whenever a request arrives, the "registry" would first be searched for the record, and if found, the latest version will be served from there. If not, it'll actually query the DB.

---

**tldr:** gap between real-time and on-demand events because of throttled `model.save()` calls, proposed optimisation is to use an in-memory store for a specific subset of records.

#### The question

**Is this an effective optimisation or am I missing the point of Mongoose, and perhaps, overlooking other, more viable / relevant solutions?**

Comment: Performance is hard for anyone else to answer as it largely relies on your code and data. How are events and operations linked? e.g. are you pushing events onto an array? How large are events? How many events per record? Can you post your model?

Comment: One thing that would be bad is continually pushing events onto an array and saving the document. That will cause mongo to rewrite the entire document out to disk every save. That could be optimised with a model change rather then a whole new system.

Answer (score 3):

**Redis**
I would suggest to take a look at Redis if you have not considered it already,  You can use Redis to save records after they are saved in MongoDB and retrieve from Redis if available, if not query MongoDB and save to redis again.

Or may be use Cassandra for both purpose ?

Comment: I'd seccond this one with both my hands up! OP's case is screaming for Redis.

Answer (score 0):

As Vipin Dubey suggested, you can cache your queries using **[Redis](https://redis.io)**. It is an in-memory data store that is commonly used for caching purposes.

I recommend the **[cachegoose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cachegoose)** module. It nicely integrates the Mongoose caching concept by storing MongoDB queries (the ones you want), and getting them from the cache when the same query is ran. Thus, you will have less calls to your database.

Redis also has various interfaces for visualizing your current values. I personally recommend [Redsmin](https://www.redsmin.com) because it provides a cross-platform web interface with an awesome editor.